# How do I care for my donkey's feet?

Tags: health, donkeys

We've recently adopted a donkey. Having no experience of donkeys, I am wondering what foot care they need, are they similar to horses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Care for your donkey's feet

- Check his feet regularly and trim his overgrown hoofs. This will help to prevent foot problems.
- Monitor the weight of your donkey. A slim donkey will hardly have foot problems unlike and overweight donkey.
- Take your donkey out for daily exercise. This will stregthen the bones in his foot.
- Take him to see your veterinary dog if you suspect foot problems like [laminitis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminitis)
- Application of hoof oil on your donkey could also help.

If you don't have much much experience in hoof trimming, you could find a [farrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farrier) that will do the job for you.